# Can you change the resolution in Jets'N'Guns?

Tags: jets-and-guns

How do I actually change the resolution in Jets'N'Guns?
In the menu there is only an option to switch to Fullscreen, which makes the game look blurry and the default resolution, which is 800x600, is too small for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest Patch after the game got released on Steam, Rake in Grass actually (finally) presented a quick solution to this Problem. While in the game, press Ctrl-K. This will open the console. The actual command to change the resolution is

```
window_size width height
```

So for example, to set the resolution to 1280x720, you have to enter

```
window_size 1280 720
```

To reset the resolution, just type `window_size` without any parameters.

---

**Additional Note**

With my QWERTZ Keyboard, I was unable to type the _ character on the console the usual way.

The console seems to ignore the country codes for your keyboard.

Use Shift+0 to type window_size correctly.